# Compile scss file with compass when it changes

Tags: macos, plist, compass-sass, sass

I'm trying to compile a scss file as soon as it changes.

I installed compass:

```
gem install compass
```

I created a plist file, `~/Library/LaunchAgents/compile_scss.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>Compass</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>compass</string>
        <string>compile</string>
        <string>/Users/name/localhost/compass/lala.scss</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/name/localhost/compass/lala.scss</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I loaded it:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/compile_scss.plist
```

And then, I changed the `lala.scss` file.

**Problem: a lala.css file is not created...**

Any idea why?

Comment: `compass watch /your/folder`?

Comment: i didn't know about this option... I'll try it, thanks. You can add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it when I get it to work.

Comment: In addition, if you don't like the command line, [Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) is an app that handles Compass and has as a bunch of other useful features that will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command: `compass watch /directory/with/your/site` to start monitoring for changes.